# Docker Nginx Mount "Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?"

Tags: docker

I've been trying to do a backup system for my dockers and everything works fine for databases containers except for the webserver's one which runs under Nginx. I've been looking around and it seems I'm not the only one having this issue, I have however not been able to find a solution.

Steps:

```
# docker load -i /path/to/backup-image.tar
# docker run \
    > -v $(pwd)/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/php-conf/custom-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini \
    > -v $(pwd)/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/php-conf/opcache-recommended.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini \
    > -v $(pwd)/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/wp-content:/var/www/html \
    > -v $(pwd)/volumes/tmp/html/.well-known:/var/www/html/.well-known \
    > --name websrv project_backup_tmp
```

This last command outputs:

```
    container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/tmp/project_restore/docker/7aa016ba40e9/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/php-conf/custom-php.ini\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b23066c3007d106ae9364ca4e2603e4d5a3e63a0f47d2669ca6580be735adb06\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b23066c3007d106ae9364ca4e2603e4d5a3e63a0f47d2669ca6580be735adb06/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/tmp/project_restore/docker/7aa016ba40e9/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/php-conf/custom-php.ini\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b23066c3007d106ae9364ca4e2603e4d5a3e63a0f47d2669ca6580be735adb06\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/b23066c3007d106ae9364ca4e2603e4d5a3e63a0f47d2669ca6580be735adb06/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Here is the result of my `docker info`:

```
Containers: 14
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 13
Images: 79
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 184
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-83-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 19.59GiB
Name: rajiska-server
ID: 4YFX:52ZF:QKGV:IMY4:6PP4:6P33:JXGT:QHJW:MZTI:QVVX:YU77:ZGR6
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: are you sure that `$(pwd)/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/php-conf/custom-php.ini` exists and is a regular file?

Comment: It's complaining about the path `$(pwd)/volumes/home/project/project-git-repo/project-docker/volumes/php-conf/custom-php.ini` not existing. Double check that

Answer (score 0):

I've across the same issue and it is generally about trying to mount a file on the host to a container running in another machine or VM.

So if the containers you're running are in a VirtualBox VM or some other machine than your local, you must find another way to sync your directories.

However, if you're using `docker-machine` to setup your VirtualBox VM, it usually mounts your `/home` directory to `/hosthome` on the created VM.

For instance, if your project is situated in your home directory, then it could be mounted like this:

```
docker run -v /hosthome/USERNAME/PROJECT:/path/on/container imagename
```

Where:

- `USERNAME` is your username on the host machine
- `PROJECT` is the name of the project directory on the host machine

Answer (score 0):

The same error appeared while setting up the elk:
The reason for the error was I had manually named the config file with a **Capital** letter **c** in my computer while in docker searching for home/imusebe/elastdocker/elasticsearch/**c**onfig/elasticsearch.yml.

Setting this got things running.